# Stale reference excpetion using phpunit selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<ul class="no-bullet" style="margin-left:0px;">
   <li>
      <a href="http://xxx/"> Accounting </a>
  </li>
   <li>
      <a href="http://xxx/"> Finance</a>
  </li>
```

I have several elements listed like this. I am using Selenium phpunit with xpaths. I gave the xpath as 
//div[14]//ul/li/a

When i did a count of the number of elements that this xpath returns, it gives me the correct number of  links in my page. But when i said click on the link, I get a StaleElementException. Can someone help?

Comment: Please add in your question the code that is causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

when the list elements count is taken...there are chances that the visual DOM elements of the page (List) is still not loaded completely...Hence, you might find issue.
work around would be  --- `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Id("id")));` and then go ahead with you click();
this works for me..